# How to create a numerical variable from Qualterly time column - R

Tags: r, date, time, data-manipulation, numerical

I have a dataset which currently looks like this:

```
Time    Var1 Var2 
2013 Q4 123  756
2013 Q4 657  987
2014 Q1 746  756
2014 Q1 66   999
2014 Q2 774  542
```

And I need to convert this categorical 'Time' variable into a numerical variable, something which may look potentially like this:

```
Time    Var1 Var2 n.Time
2013 Q4 123  756  1
2013 Q4 657  987  1
2014 Q1 746  756  2
2014 Q1 66   999  2
2014 Q2 774  542  3
```

Or something similar which gives the 'Time' column a numerical value which is proportional.

I have attempted the

```
df$n.Time <- as.yearqtr(df$Time)
```

But this just gives the same output as the 'Time' column instead of making it numerical.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
df$n.Time <- as.numeric(as.factor(df$Time))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for splitting `Q` part, from `Time` column and then change it a numerical value.

```
df$n.Time <- as.factor(substr(as.character(df$Time),
             gregexpr("Q",df$Time),nchar(as.character(df$Time))))
```